# Dates not converting to MM/dd/yyy

Tags: c#, date

I have a flat file that has some dates coming in as m/d/yy and some as mm/dd/yy.  I am trying to convert them all to MM/dd/yy with no success.
The code is below.  Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
StudentRec.birthdate = fields[i];
string[] format = { "MM/dd/yy" };
DateTime dateValue;
if (StudentRec.birthdate.Length > 0)
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(StudentRec.birthdate, format,
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces , 
                                out dateValue))
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(StudentRec.birthdate);
        throw new MyException("Birthdate is not valid   ", o, strCNFileErr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this any language in particular?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to the problem: what is it doing and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: Dates are coming in as either 05/09/16 or 5/9/16 I need to convert all of the 5/9/16 to 05/09/16.

Comment: "what is it doing and how does that differ from what you want?"

Comment: It is not converting.  It's a string coming in and I am converting it to a date MM/dd/yy but still shows 5/9/16 not 05/09/16.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the second valid date format. It will attempt each one until it succeeds.

```
StudentRec.birthdate = fields[i];
string[] format = { "MM/dd/yy", "M/d/yy" };  // Valid formats. 
DateTime dateValue;
if (StudentRec.birthdate.Length > 0)
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(StudentRec.birthdate, format,
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces , 
                                out dateValue))
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(StudentRec.birthdate);
        throw new MyException("Birthdate is not valid   ", o, strCNFileErr);
    }
}
```

Note: The first format that works will return.

Comment: @ScottHunter Hes not trying to output. Hes trying to parse the input.

Comment: I'm a newb to c# anyway.

Comment: @MWatson Dont forget to mark the answer as correct.